# How are Virtual Bytes allocated?

Tags: windows, iis, memory

- At the start of a Windows user-mode process, what determines the initial size of its [Virtual Address Space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space)?
- What makes Virtual Bytes fluctuate during the lifetime of a process?

As per [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space-and-physical-storage):

> The total amount of virtual address space available to a process is limited by physical memory and the free space on disk available for the paging file.

- Does that mean that Virtual Bytes can do *down* if the amount of free disk space goes down?
- Can it go up just because more disk space became available?

### Background

An ASP.NET Webforms website of mine that runs on a shared hosting platform started failing with 503 errors. After adding some diags, I saw that the app was restarting very frequently (every minute at busy times) until it eventually died (503).

Further debugging showed that the app starts with around 1.2-1.5 Gb of [Process.VirtualMemorySize64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.virtualmemorysize64?view=net-5.0). The hosting provider has Virtual Memory Limit set to 1.5 Gb in IIS App Pool settings. No wonder the process gets shot down in a matter of minutes.

Which led me to the questions above.

Comment: Learning some basic concepts of operating system memory management (not only for Windows or .NET) should help you answer the questions yourself, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory. The real problem here is "the app starts with around 1.2-1.5 Gb", as a healthy application shouldn't be like that. Microsoft has tips in articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/high-memory-level and you might learn how to use a memory profiler to investigate further on your local IIS.

Answer (score 1):

> At the start of a Windows user-mode process, what determines the initial size of its Virtual Address Space?

Sections in a PE32 executable have virtual memory sizes.

> What makes Virtual Bytes fluctuate during the lifetime of a process?

Memory allocations; i.e. what happens when you `new[]` something (if you're familiar with libc, what `malloc` does under the hood. If you're from a Linux background, the Windows equivalent of `sbrk`).

The process can use syscalls to allocate more virtual memory; on modern systems, that does *not* automatically reserve memory. It just makes addresses valid to use for the process, but the first access to an unreserved page will (transparently to the process) fail, raise an exception that the NT kernel handles, which then actually takes some memory and adds it to the page table for that address (range).

> Does that mean that Virtual Bytes can do down if the amount of free disk space goes down?
> Can it go up just because more disk space became available?

No. Virtual Memory is an address space. That address space can be backed by actual RAM, it can not be backed at all (i.e. not yet used the first time), or it can be written to a paging file ("swapped") on disk, the used RAM was marked unused, and on the next attempt to access that area of memory, that will transparently fail, the kernel will load the memory from disk to some currently unused RAM page, then map that to the virtual address in question.

---

you might want to revisit how virtual memory, logical memory and physical memory addresses are handled, in general.

---

> Further debugging showed that the app starts with around 1.2-1.5 Gb of Process.VirtualMemorySize64.

"b" is for bits, you probably mean "GB", Gigabytes; anyway, this is really a lot of memory that your runtime pre-allocated. Very few things in life use that much memory.

> The hosting provider has Virtual Memory Limit set to 1.5 Gb in IIS App Pool settings. No wonder the process gets shot down in a matter of minutes.

Sounds reasonable. Unless you're actually implementing a large-scale database, a full browser, a 3D game or a thousand-user chatserver in your process, that should actually suffice.

As Lex Li [points out in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558170/how-are-virtual-bytes-allocated/67558286#comment119411740_67558170),  your memory usage warrants suspicion. You might want to [figure out where your memory usage stems from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/high-memory-level).